# How to enable customers to use their own domain for sites hosted by me

Tags: domains

I am thinking of running a self-site builder. But was wondering how would I allow customers to use their own domains that they already own.

Is that even possible?

Let's say my site is www.bestsitebuildingwebsite.com and each customer has urls like this

www.bestsitebuildingwebsite.com/frances
www.bestsitebuildingwebsite.com/eden
www.bestsitebuildingwebsite.com/john

And a customer has a domain called widgets.com

Is it actually possible domain widgets.com to go to my site somehow and have HASHES on the URL still work (my site makes use of hashes for AJAX queries). And their site still have good SEO with Google?

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but your customers would have to update their DNS records.

This is how it works -

1. Point widgets.com to your IP Address
2. Modify your code to infer the customer from the host name
3. AJAX code should post to widgets.com and not to www.bestsitebuildingwebsite.com. Since they are both the same servers, it shouldn't be a problem.
4. If you set any cookies on www.bestsitebuildingwebsite.com, they will not be available on widgets.com. You will need some kind of federated authentication to solve that problem.

Comment: This is a great start! I'll do more research into this. If anyone else have more info or have done this before, please let me know.